# I added a switch widget to the app' menu (android studio) and the app keeps crashing. Can someone help me fix it?

Tags: android, menu, android-switch

The menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idSwitchColor"
        android:title="Switch"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/use_switch"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu, menu);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);

        MenuItem itemSwitch = menu.findItem(R.id.idSwitchColor);
        itemSwitch.setActionView(R.layout.use_switch);
        final Switch swi= (Switch) itemSwitch.getActionView();

        swi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(swi.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Bye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

I tried debugging and it crashes at the OnClickListener part (at least from what I could tell, I'm not very good at this). Thanks in advance to anyone who can try and help me! Would really mean a lot

Comment: Hi, ${username}, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding the error log/stack trace from the crash which should be logged in Logcat, as well as a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're facing.

Comment: where do I find the error log?

Comment: See this documentation from the Android Developers site: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Add `use_switch.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `setActionView` in java code, you already added `actionView` in your menu.
if you want to use your layout file, make sure the root view of `use_switch.xml` is `Switch` otherwise, it will throw `ClassCastException`.

> [ClassCastException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassCastException)

and if you don't want to use it, you can delete this:

```
itemSwitch.setActionView(R.layout.use_switch);
```

Comment: Sorry but how do I make sure the root view is Switch? where do I find it and what do I need to change if it isn't Switch?

Comment: @13fjuk Please add `use_switch.xml`